# charismathics pkcs11 dll (cmp11.dll) error

Tags: dll, smartcard, pkcs#11

I have a Charismathics cssi middleware, and I want to use it with my smartcards. When I want to add its pkcs11 dll (cmp11.dll) file to my Security Devices, It gives an error "Unable to add module".
Does Anybody use Charismathics pkcs11 dll successfully?
Thanks in advance.

Comment: Maybe I'm stating the obvious here, but have you tried Charismathics? Do you have a log file? Do you have a matching environment (64 bit/32 bit) ?

Comment: I can't locate log file. My Windows is 32 bit, and my Charismathics is 32 bits too.

Comment: Is your smartcard tested with charismatics? There is no such thing as a generic card, so some (or a lot) of work is required to use cards with middleware by definition.

Comment: my cards are kona25 from tagsystems, charismathics claims that support them, isn't it enough?

@owlstead Do you have charismathics? did you test cmp11.dll for some cards?

Comment: No I don't, at the company I work for we mostly write our own middle-ware or use complete solutions.